# laravel 7 role base authentication sharing session cookies user can accsess admin panel without any restriction how to solve this problem

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

I'm using laravel 7 i was created roll base authentication using laravel UI, when i tried cross check logged with user in chrome browser, in edge browser i was logged with as admin, after i shared cookies by using inspect-application copied admin cookies and replaced chrome user cookies with admin cookies and refreshed page after refreshing page i get admin access with admin credential. how to solve this problem pls help.[image]

Comment: *"I'm using laravel 7,8..."* you can't have both versions at the same time! Which, exact, version do you have ?

Comment: @this he mentioned 7,8 means 2 different versions he tried

Comment: @this I'm tried in both version

Comment: Though I am not 100% sure, this is related to `HttpOnly` attribute of your cookies from my understanding. A good web security practice to prevent access from client-side scripting.

Comment: @Elvis ur right this is not HttpOnly it having some other problem from laravel is there any suggestion pls tell

Comment: Maybe try setting `HttpOnly` attribute to True to prevent client-side scripting from accessing the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is adding 'password.confirm' middleware to your sensitive routes
like admin dashboard ex:**

```
Route::middleware('password.confirm')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/dashboard',[AdminDashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('.index');
});
```

i hope it was useful .

Comment: im getting error ErrorException
Array to string conversion     public function register($routes)

    {

        $router = $this->router;

 

        require $routes;

    }

Comment: i used laravel 8 with breeze